# How to loop through all CSV files, open each, and perform some operations on each?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to loop through all CSV files in a folder, open each, do some find/replace things, then save and close each CSV.  Here is my code, which should be close, I think, but apparently something is off because it's not working.

```
import glob
path = "C:\\Users\\ryans\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\downloads\\Products\\*.csv"
for fname in glob.glob(path):
    print(str(fname))
    with open(str(fname)) as f:
        newText = f.read().replace('|', ',').replace(' ', '')

with open(str(fname), "w") as f:
    f.write(newText)
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: the `write` statement is not in your for-loop so you will only write the last .csv file. Also you will overwrite the old csv file, but that might be your plan.

Comment: the indentation is wrong.

Comment: Yes, I want to make the changes I described and overwrite the old file with the new (transformed) file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should finish the operation and close the file in your for loop.

please also note that it is more elegant to use raw strings for a path rather than escaping each backslash

```
import glob
path = r"C:\Users\ryans\OneDrive\Desktop\downloads\Products\*.csv"
for fname in glob.glob(path):
    print(str(fname))
    with open(str(fname), "w") as f:
        newText = f.read().replace('|', ',').replace(' ', '')
        f.write(newText)
```

Comment: Thanks Marc.  This looks like it should work, but I'm getting something very weird over here.  When I run this line: path = 'C:/Users/ryans/OneDrive/Desktop/downloads/Products/*.csv'
I actually get this result printed out: C:/Users/ryans/OneDrive/Desktop/downloads/Products\ARMINDEX.CSV  Why would the last slash be reversed?

Answer (score 1):

```
import glob

path = "path/to/dir/*.csv"

for fname in glob.glob(path):
    print(fname)
    with open((fname), "w") as f:
        newText = f.read().replace('|', ',').replace(' ', '')
        f.write(newText)
        f.close()
```

Comment: That looks absolutely correct to me, but when I run the code I get this result:
newText = f.read().replace('|', ',').replace(' ', '')

It is actually deleting all the data in the first file and saving a blank file with no data.  Ugh.
UnsupportedOperation: not readable

Comment: I think the problem is that you can't do the find/replace in the file and save it with the same name.  Is that right?

Comment: add f.close() after f.write(newText)

Answer (score 0):

use Pandas Library to read the csv file and replace the value with the intended one.

```
df['range'] = df['range'].str.replace(',','-')
```

range is the column name.
and save it by following

```
df.to_csv(file_name, sep=',')
```

or without using a ibrary

```
with open(resource,'rb') as f, open("output.txt", "a+") as outputfile:
for line in f:
    line = line.replace(' ', '-')
    outputfile.write(line)
```

Comment: I don't want to loop column by column, I want to make all changes to each file in a single pass.

Comment: then do df.replace(',', '-')

Comment: your solution, while valid, introduces a dependancy on an external library. This problem can easily be solved with standard functions.

Comment: like this?
`with open(resource,'rb') as f, open("output.txt", "w") as outputfile:`
   ` for line in f:`
        
        `line = line.replace(' ', '-')`
        `outputfile.write(line)`